# Enable horizontal scrolling for main div

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a main div and a sidebar on the right (for navigation/filters). The main div is being used for showing logfiles and under no circumstances it should write into the right sidebar.

**The problem:**
When a very long message without spaces (for example a long filepath) appears, it will write into my right sidebar. Instead I would like to have an own horizantal scrollbar for this div.

**The code:** I have created a JSFiddle which demonstrates the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/pu9b5pu2/

It is about these two divs here:

```
<div class="col-xs-9">
         <div class="debug">
            <div class="timestamp">[09:33:04.137] </div>
            <div class="message">BlaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaBlaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaBlaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaBlaaaaBlaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
         </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Right side bar -->
      <div class="col-xs right-sidebar">
         <div id="title-sidebar">
            <strong id="title">Filters</strong>
         </div>
         <input type="checkbox" id="debug" value="value">
         <label for="debug">Debug messages</label>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `overflow: auto;` to the `.col-xs-9` container.

Change this line from your JSFiddle:

`<div class="col-xs-9" style="white-space: normal; word-wrap: break-word; overflow-wrap: break-word;">`

To this:

`<div class="col-xs-9" style="white-space: normal; word-wrap: break-word; overflow-wrap: break-word; overflow: auto;">`

And optionally, so the text isn't flush to the right when you scroll all the way, you can add `padding-right: 15px;` to the `.message` element.

Comment: Thanks, that was easy and also thanks for the padding idea.

Comment: Any idea how I could prevent that a long message would start in a new line instead of next to the timestamp, example: http://i.imgur.com/wlPLAEb.png ?

Answer (score 1):

You can break long words with CSS:

```
.break-word {
  hyphens: auto;// requires lang attribute be set on target element or ancestor
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

- https://justmarkup.com/log/2015/07/dealing-with-long-words-in-css/
- https://kenneth.io/blog/2012/03/04/word-wrapping-hypernation-using-css/
- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/prevent-long-urls-from-breaking-out-of-container/
- https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/word-break/